# Define Url String?

Tags: php, html, url

So basically i am generating some tv-shows and episodes with this code but i am scaping from another website

**But the website shows its links like this**
- http://afdah.to/embed5/3107288s01e09

**While my website shows links like** 
- http://movie25.com/supergirl/3107288s1e9 (the end numbers is what links both site)

The difference between the two urls is that their website adds a zero to any number less than 10.

I am a total rokie with coding so i was wondering is there a way to define in the code
to add a zero in the url to numbers below 10

Let me exaplain what this code those it scraps links from imdb.com.

```
 $idsseries = The series number, which would be this above (3107288)
 $seson     = Season number 
 $epi       = Episode number
```

So basically i would want to add a code to $season  and  $epi; basically saying that it should 'add 0 to numbers between 1-9. It would have to be dined fro both episode and season.

**This is the code**

```
<?php

$idsseries = series_get_meta('ids');
$jsons_aka = file_get_contents('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/'.$idsseries.'?api_key=05902896074695709d7763505bb88b4d&append_to_response=external_ids');
$uncompressed = json_decode($jsons_aka);
$idsseries= $uncompressed->external_ids->imdb_id;
$seson = info_movie_get_meta( 'temporada' );
$epi = info_movie_get_meta( 'episodio' );
$idsseries_e = $idsseries.'-'.$seson.'-'.$epi;
echo '<iframe src="http://afdah.to/embed5/'.$idsseries.'s'.$seson.'e'.$epi.'" height="100%"  allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
?>
```

Comment: Are you opposed to a solution that uses regex with negative lookbehinds and negative lookaheads?

Comment: As i stated i am a newbie. I just had to even lookup what you replied with. So please, yes! Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if these return `numbers`, you can format them into `string` as:

```
// these are numbers
$seson_num = info_movie_get_meta('temporada');
$epi_num = info_movie_get_meta('episodio');

// format into 2 digits string, 0 padded
$seson = sprintf("%02d", $seson_num);
$epi = sprintf("%02d", $epi_num);
```

Whereas if they return `string`, then convert `string` to `int` before apply `sprintf`:

```
// these are strings
$seson_string = info_movie_get_meta('temporada');
$epi_string = info_movie_get_meta('episodio');

// convert string to int, then apply sprintf
$seson = sprintf("%02d", (int)$seson_string);
$epi = sprintf("%02d", (int)$epi_string);
```

Then just concatenate them into your final `url string`.

**Note:**

As newly asked in comment below, to strip away `tt` in `tt3107288`:

```
$original_string = 'tt3107288';

// this outputs: 3107288
$string = preg_replace('/^tt/', '', original_string);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, i have one other question.When     $idsseries   is generated in the code it generates with 'tt' infront of the number '3107288'; example 'tt3107288',

basically i want the same thing done but i want it to remove 'tt'

Comment: @MachelaLimited I already added in my answer about how to remove `tt` in the string.

Comment: I dont want it to be specific for (3107288) because this number is generated and is never the same. 

This is what i want it to remove the 'tt' in - $idsseries

Comment: @MachelaLimited `tt3107288` is just an example string, that code snippet in my answer works with any string that starts with `tt`.